# Updating an array within mongdbo document [Golang]

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to update an array item within a mongo document.

Event is the Document, which i'm finding with the event id, then i need to identify which object in the task array needs to be changed by identifying the name of the task.

Any idea where i'm going wrong

Event Stuct

```golang
type Event struct {
EventId              string       `json:"eventid" bson:"eventid"`
EventOwner           string       `json:"eventowner" bson:"eventowner"`
EventTitle           string       `json:"eventtitle" bson:"eventtitle"`
EventDateTime        string       `json:"eventdatetime" bson:"eventdatetime"`
EventLocation        EventAddress `json:"eventlocation" bson:"eventlocation"`
EventTotalTicket     int          `json:"eventtotalticket" bson:"eventtotalticket"`
EventAvailableTicket int          `json:"eventavailableticket" bson:"eventavailableticket"`
EventCoverImage      string       `json:"eventcoverimage" bson:"eventcoverimage"`
EventDescription     string       `json:"eventdescription" bson:"eventdescription"`
Lat                  string       `json:"lat" bson:"lat"`
Long                 string       `json:"long" bson:"long"`
Task                 []Task       `json:"task" bson:"task"`
}
```

Task Struct:

```golang
type Task struct {
TaskTitle    string  `json:"tasktitle" bson:"tasktitle"`
InitalBudget float32 `json:"initialbudget" bson:"initialbudget"`
Supplier     string  `json:"suppid" bson:"suppid"`
AgreedPrice  float32 `json:"agreedprice" bson:"agreedprice"`
IsComplete   bool    `json:"iscomplete" bson:"iscomplete"`
}
```

Here's what i'm trying to do

```golang
func (e *EventServiceImpl) UpdateTask(eventid *string, task *models.Task) error {

    //filter := bson.D{bson.E{Key: "eventid", Value: eventid}, bson.E{Key: "tasktitle", Value: task.TaskTitle}}
    filter := bson.M{"$and": []bson.M{{"eventid": eventid}, {"task": bson.E{Key: "tasktitle", Value: task.TaskTitle}}}}
    update := bson.D{bson.E{Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{bson.E{Key: "task", Value: bson.M{"tasktitle": task.TaskTitle, "initialbudget": task.InitalBudget, "suppid": task.Supplier, "agreedprice": task.AgreedPrice, "iscomplete": task.IsComplete}}}}}
    result, _ := e.eventcollection.UpdateOne(e.ctx, filter, update)
    if result.MatchedCount != 1 {
        return errors.New("No matched document found to update")
    }
    return nil

}
```

I always receive the "No matched document found to update"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution

```golang
func (e *EventServiceImpl) UpdateTask(eventid *string, task *models.Task) error {
    filter := bson.M{"eventid": eventid, "task": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"tasktitle": task.TaskTitle}}}
    update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"task.$.initialbudget": task.InitalBudget, "task.$.suppid": task.Supplier, "task.$.agreedprice": task.AgreedPrice, "task.$.iscomplete": task.IsComplete}}
    result, err := e.eventcollection.UpdateOne(e.ctx, filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if result.MatchedCount != 1 {
        return errors.New("No matched document found to update")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).